# How to know if an Image is in memory in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I have a screen in my app with an image as the background, this image is on my asset folder. When I navigate to this screen the background is blank for an instant and then the image is loaded and it appears. This makes my screen look weird for a half a second or less, but enough for the user to notice.

I wanted to be able to only navigate to that screen once the image is loaded (I can wait on the previous screen), so I can avoid this behavior and have the screen as a whole when the user navigates there.

I know can make the image fade in, but that's not the experience that I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [ImageProvider.resolve](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/ImageProvider/resolve.html) method

So suppose you have some image registered in you assets.
Then you may obtain the image provider as

`_imageProvider = Image.asset("your_asset").image`.

Then you may add such method:

```
import 'dart:ui';

Image _image;
bool _resolved;

void _resolveImageProvider() {
    ImageStream stream = _imageProvider.resolve(createLocalImageConfiguration(context));
    stream.addListener(ImageStreamListener((info, _) {
      setState(() {
        //here you may set some flags or anything which indicates the image is in memory now.
        _resolved = true;
        _image = info.image;
      });
    }));
  }
```

Then you can call this method on the "previous screen", wait till the listener is triggered and only then navigate to the next view.

Comment: Interesting! So I guess once an image is loaded in memory it sits there in a cache? So further loading of the same image is "instantaneous"?

Comment: It's not that simple. Asset images are cached by framework but how exactly on the technical implementation level I can't say.
For images from network there's a package https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image to cache them on disk I believe.

Comment: In the API doc for `ImageProvider` it says `ImageProvider uses the global imageCache to cache images`. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/ImageProvider-class.html

Comment: What about `precacheImage` won't it be simpler?

Comment: Absolutely. As I see from the code of `prechaceImage` it is the same but with all the little things like removing the listener and error handling :)